# structure variable is not set to 0 after applying the memset

Tags: c

I want to know, how the value is printed for the below items. because i set the structure variable one to 0 using memset. but this variable is assigned in mainst.subst using init() method.

printf("\n %d",mainst.subst.t1);
printf("\n %d",mainst.subst.t2);

Please kindly let me any one know why its print like that.

Source Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct one *oneptr;

struct one
{
        char t1;
        char t2;
        char *path;
};
typedef struct one one_st;

struct char_ar
{
        int a;
        char b;
        one_st subst;
}mainst;

void init(oneptr cp)
{
        mainst.a=10;
        mainst.b='u';
        mainst.subst=*cp;
}

void main()
{
        oneptr ptr;
        struct one o;
        o.t1='t';
        o.t2='u';
        o.path = malloc(10);
        strcpy(o.path,"HI");

        init( &o);

        ptr = &o;
        free(ptr->path);
        ptr->path=(char *)NULL;

        memset ((char *)ptr, 0, sizeof(one_st));

        printf("\n %d",mainst.subst.t1);
        printf("\n %d",mainst.subst.t2);
        printf("\n %s",mainst.subst.path);

}
```

Comment: What was printed? And what did you *expect* to be printed?

Comment: two notable problems: 1) mainst.subst=*cp; will NOT copy the whole cp struct.  suggest: memcpy(mainst.subst, cp, sizeof( struct one);  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc() to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `memset` on `o`, which is a stack allocated structure.  But you are printing the contents of `mainst`, which is a different value in your data segment.  So the call to `memset` has no effect on your program.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i assigned `mainst.subst=*cp;` where `cp` has the address of structure variable `o`. While accessing the value `mainst.subst` which points to structure variable `o`. is it right? Correct me if i wrong.

Comment: @user2815465 That just copied the contents of `o` into `mainst.subst`.  But `mainst.subst` is not a pointer, it's a structure embedded in `mainst` which is in your heap.  Totally different memory from `o`.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `mainst.subst=*cp;`  , it sets `mainst.subst.path` to point to the same place as `ptr->path`, i.e. the block that you `malloc'd`.  So you have one memory block with two pointers pointing to it.

But then you have:

```
free(ptr->path);
// ...
printf("\n %s",mainst.subst.path);
```

`ptr->path` and `mainst.subst.path` both point to the same block which you allocated via `malloc`.  You free that block, and then you pass the address of that block to `printf`.  Using the address of a freed block causes [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939).

---

Note that your `memset` did not even try to write into the freed block. You scrubbed all over `o` but that has no effect on memory being pointed to by a member of `o` because you did not follow the pointer.

Perhaps what you meant to do was something like:

```
ptr = &o;
memset(ptr->path, 0, 10);
free(ptr->path);
```

however it would still cause undefined behaviour to use `mainst.subst.path` because it still points to a freed block.